# find $a$ and $b$ where $x^3 - 4x^2 -3x + 18 = (x+a)(x-b)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, cubics

I have a problem solving this as when I match the coefficients to the expanded brackets I end up with $2$ unknowns $a \& b$. So cannot substitute any values to find the other. According to the answers $a=2$ and $b=3$ but I cannot get there. Would someone be able to provide a worked through example so I can figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your work of matching the coefficients? In particular, if you can get a linear expression like (say) $ 4 = a + 2b $, then we can substitute that into the other equations.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)?

Comment: I have 1 linear expression: -2b + a = -4

Comment: I also have 2 quadratic expressions: b^2 - 2ab = -3, and ab^2 = 18, thank you for your help

Comment: expanding the brackets gives: x^3 - 2bx^2 + b^2x + ax^2 - 2abx + ab^2

Answer (score 0):

$x^3 - 4x^2 -3x + 18 = (x+a)(x-b)^2 = (x+a)(x^2-2bx+b^2)=x^3+(a-2b)x^2+(b^2-2ab)x+ab^2$

$a-2b=-4$, $a=2b-4$

$b^2-2ab=-3$

$ab^2=18$

$b^2-2ab= b^2 - 2b(2b-4)=-3b^2+8b=-3$

$3b^2-8b-3=(3b+1)(b-3)=0$, $b=\frac{-1}{3}, a=\frac{-14}{3}$(NA) or $b=3,a=2$

Comment: Thank you for this, I will work though it and try to figure it out. The worked through example I was given for  a different question in the material was so basic in comparison to this question. Seems like a ridiculous jump in what I am expected to be able to answer in one question. But if I can get my head round it, will be worth it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm there now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

your conditions say that there is a nontrivial common factor  in
$x^3 - 4x^2 -3x + 18 $   and its derivative $3x^2 -8x -3 $
The next to last line below is a Bezout type formula...

We can investigate  that using  the Euclidean algorithm

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 18 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  3 x^{2}  - 8 x  - 3 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 18 \right)  =  \left(  3 x^{2}  - 8 x  - 3 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 4 }{ 9 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 50 x  + 150 }{ 9 }  \right)  $$
$$  \left(  3 x^{2}  - 8 x  - 3 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 50 x  + 150 }{ 9 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 27 x  - 9 }{ 50 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$
$$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 4 }{ 9 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 4 }{ 9 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$
$$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 27 x  - 9 }{ 50 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 9 x^{2}  + 9 x  + 54 }{ 50 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 27 x  - 9 }{ 50 }  \right) } $$
$$  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 6 \right)  \left( \frac{ 9}{50 } \right)  -  \left(  3 x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 4 }{ 50 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$
$$  \mbox{confirming  GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) }   $$
$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 18 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 6 \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(  3 x^{2}  - 8 x  - 3 \right)  =  \left(  3 x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$
$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 18 \right)  \left( \frac{ 9}{50 } \right)  -  \left(  3 x^{2}  - 8 x  - 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 4 }{ 50 }  \right)  =  \color{blue}{  \left(   -  x  + 3 \right)  } $$
$$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{blue}{  \left(   x  - 3 \right) }   $$

The conclusion is that $(x-3)^2$  divides
$x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  - 3 x  + 18.$  So, divide the original by $x^2 - 6 x + 9,$  the quotient will be some $x +a$